# What is Josh doing?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, image-identification

[image]

I don't even know if there's a word for this kind of action, in any language. Is there? If there isn't, there ought to be one.

He's shielding his eyes from the light in order to facilitate his ... what, exactly? Hunters and ship captains do it too. As well as lovesick fair maidens awaiting their knights scheduled to return from their dragon-slaying expeditions.

Comment: Thanks for posting this painting...it's a real work of art.  You know it's art because it has inspired discussion and thinking.  Who's the artist?  Judging from the clothing, it looks to be 1810.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: That would be Sir Joshua Reynolds.

Comment: Are you asking why anyone would shield his eyes when gazing?

Comment: @deadrat: No. Yes. I don't know. You tell me.

Comment: I can't tell you what you're really asking.  I can tell you why people shade their eyes, but it has nothing to do with English usage.

Comment: Why this is tagged *image-identification* is beyond me. The OP doesn't want to know the image's name, or who painted the portrait.  must say when I first saw the title I thought the question was referring to user Josh61, a surefire sign I have spent / wasted too much time on EL&U... Once again, could I urge the OP to write a more descriptive title, for the benefit of future visitors (and mankind?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Reynolds to read more about Sir Joshua Reynolds and see some of his other self-portraits

Answer (score 7):

I would say that he is "shading" his eyes.

Comment: Well, yes, he is, but that's not everything he's doing. Why is he shading them? To make what easier?

Comment: Shading the eyes to make seeing something off in the distance easier

Comment: @Ricky: He is shading his eyes to cut down on [*glare*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glare_(vision)).

Comment: It's a self portrait and the items he's holding are a palette and a hand stick to steady the hand while painting detail.  He probably situated himself in sunlight indoors to get the best lighting and had to shield his eyes from the glare.

Comment: You should add that second comment in your post. The action of [shielding](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/ripararsi) / shading / protecting one's sight from the sun's glare (thanks ermanen) is an instinctive reaction. There's even a dictionary entry:  [to shade one's eyes from the sun](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-italian/to-shade-one-s-eyes-from-the-sun)

Comment: Even the self-portrait itself is called "shading the eyes": http://www.wallacecollection.org/blog/2015/01/a-man-of-masks/

Answer (score 4):

If I were describing this, I would say "He cast a searching gaze toward the horizon."

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gaze

**Gaze** is often used to express emotion, particularly longing, but can also equally be comfortably used to describe a fixed intent.  "He gazed at the clock."  In uses I remember seeing, the writer will further clarify *gaze*, so in the above sentence, I think it would add more to say "He gazed at the clock, thinking of the time when he could leave and return to his true passion."  Odysseus gazed at the ocean dreaming of his return to Ithica, or perhaps Newton gazed at the heavens in wonder.

For your painting, the title could read "Josh's Gaze." "The Gaze of the Mariner" or "The Gaze of the Lover."

Comment: Well, yeah, and he could also be surveying, and even observing (even though that's a stretch), but there's more to it, I think. More purpose, more intent, more ... hmm ...

Comment: I think he's looking at those French heels you favor.

Comment: @deadrat well he can't have them because I need them for my other job.

Comment: You can gaze at something without placing a hand above your eyes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA true...now that I think of it he is shading his eyes...but gaze sounds more poetic.

Comment: "cast a gaze" is nice too :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say, *he is **scanning the horizon***. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scanning+the+horizon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscanning%20the%20horizon%3B%2Cc0)

> scan: to look at all parts of (something) carefully in order to detect some feature [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/scan)
>
> *“Well, I told him that the crow's nest and scanning the horizon are a kind of an apprenticeship if he wants to become a sailor."* [The Rediscovery of the Bewitched Archipelago](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GGSPCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT59&dq=%22scanning+the+horizon%22+Josh&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHqtqHkqTJAhXL1hoKHTkmANUQ6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=%22scanning%20the%20horizon%22%20Josh&f=false)